# Why echo function is not printing anything here?

Tags: shell, if-statement, echo

In this shellscript, I have created 3 functions.
It will take 2 command line arguments. first for the type of the operation and second for a string to perform something on it..
Here, my echo command in any of the functions is not printing anything..

Any Help would be appreciated.

```
clear

lower()
{
echo $2 | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"
}

upper()
{
echo $2 | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"
}

proper()
{
echo $2 | sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g'
}


#echo "Enter The Option and then the string to perform the operation:"
echo $1 $2 '> echo $1 $2 '

if [ $1 = "-l" ]
then
lower $2
elif [ $1 = "-u" ]
then
upper $2
elif [ $1 = "-p" ] 
then 
proper $2
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of a function, `$1`, `$2`, etc., refer to the command-line arguments to the program. Inside of a function, they are the *function's* arguments. Change all of the `echo $2`'s to `echo $1`.

Style improvements:

- By default, always quote variable expansions. Write `"$1"` and `"$2"` instead of bare `$1` and `$2`. That way if those arguments have spaces or globs they'll expand to one word instead of many.
- The `if`/`elif` chain at the bottom could be replaced with a `case` block.

  ```
  case "$1" in
      -l) lower "$2";;
      -u) upper "$2";;
      -p) proper "$2";;
  esac
  ```
- Putting `clear` at the top of a script is kind of an annoying DOS-ism. On Linux, I don't want scripts I run clearing my terminal as if they know best. Either get rid of the `clear`; or, if you want to be fancy, add `tput smcup` at the top and `tput rmcup` at the bottom to save and restore the terminal. That's what programs like `less` and `vim` do to draw to the whole screen and then restore the original terminal contents when they exit.

Comment: Hey John Thanks but , is there anything wrong with the use of if/elif statement?

Comment: Using `echo "$1"` in the functions solves the immediate problem, but it also means that the functions will look at their first argument and silently ignore any following arguments. For example, `lower FOO BAR` will print just `foo`.  That's fine if it's what you want, but `echo "$*"` or `echo "$@"` is more general. (Even then, passing `-n` could cause odd behavior. If that's a concern, use `printf` rather than `echo`.)

Answer (score 1):

Inside each function, replace `$2` with `$1`.

```
  lower()
  {
    echo $1 | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"  
  }
```

For your script and also for your function, `$1` represents the first argument and `$2` second. If you are going to provide two arguments to your script, but one argument to your function, then it should be,

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" "$2"

func_echo(){
 echo "func $1"
}
# Call the function
func_echo $2
```

Resulted in:

```
$ ./test.sh "first" "second"
first second
func second
```